# setting up a WGR614v7 behind a linux box

Tags: linux, dhcp, wireless-networking, opensuse

Here's the setup, I have an openSUSE box with 2 NICs, one goes to my home network router, the other has DHCP running and it attached to a wireless router.  I'm trying to get this setup to work before I switch to the linux box as my home network router.  My DHCP will offer the wireless router (a WGR614v7) an address, but anything that connects to the wireless router ends up with a APIPA address.  I have all the firewalls on the wireless network turned off as well as the wireless router's own DHCP.  The linux box isn't offering addresses to anything past the wireless router.  Is this a problem with the router or my DHCP setup?  For testing purposes, I have both NICs set in the internal zone and I've tried wireless and wired connections to the WGR614v7 both to no avail.

Comment: Please read our FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Ethernet jack on the WGR614 is connected to the OpenSuSE machine?

I suspect you've used the WAN (uplink) port.  If so, no DHCP service will be available to devices downstream of the WGR614 because the WGR614's DHCP server is disabled and the OpenSuSE machine's DHCP server is in a different network segment.

If you want the Linux machine to provide DHCP service to the devices that connect to the WGR614, you'll need to connect the Linux machine to a WGR614 LAN port, not its WAN port.  In this configuration, the WGR614's routing/firewalling/NAT functionality will be unused and the device will serve only as an Ethernet switch and a wireless access point.  Make sure you keep the WGR614's DHCP server disabled in this configuration.

Comment: That did it.  I switched the linux-to-WGR614 cable from the uplink port to a regular LAN port, connected, and got an IP address from my linux box.  Now I'm faced with no internet connectivity from the my side of the linux box but that's a different problem all together.  Thanks for the help.